# Charging process of a battery

Tags: battery-charging, charging

I apologize if my question seems ordinary and silly. Unfortunately, I have not good electronic knowledge. but the question is as follow:
assume we have a power source like solar panels that produce power P. in other hand we have two batteries namely B1 and B2 with terminal voltages V1 and V2 correspondingly. What is the charging current of B1 or B2 if I decide assign power P to each of them. Are they obtained by $$I_1 = P/V_1$$ and $$I_2 = P/V_2$$
If s, then can we conclude that $$Q_1 = I_1*T$$ is more or less than $$Q_2 = I_2*T$$ In other words can we conclude that in one scenario we obtain more charge than the other one???

Comment: Unless the scenarios are identical in every way, how could the conclusion not be that one system obtains more charge than the other?

Comment: And of course you're assuming that the **voltage** of the solar panels is greater than that of the batteries to start with as you do not mention anything about voltage conversion. No matter how much power a panel can produce if the output voltage is less than the battery terminal voltage it cannot charge the battery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't assume that a given solar panel delivers constant power. The power that it delivers depends on both the amount of light it is receiving and the load that it is connected to.

Under full illumination, a given solar panel will produce a certain maximum open-circuit voltage. It can also deliver a certain maximum current into a short circuit. Since power is voltage times current, the maximum power will fall somewhere in between.

Connecting batteries of different voltages directly to the panel will put it at different points on its "operating curve". The one with the lower voltage will generally get more charge (amp-hours) — but not necessarily more energy (watt-hours). But your oversimplified calculation is not the right way to estimate the difference. You'll need to have specific data for the panel and the batteries in question.

A Maximum Power Point Tracker (MPPT) circuit is specifically designed to adapt a solar panel to a battery, varying the battery voltage (and current) so that all of the power available from the panel from moment to moment can be used.